# Render HTMLAudioElement DOM element with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twilio, twilio-api

I'm using Twillio JS API in my project to display video outputs from multiple sources. This API generates enumeration of DOM video/audio elements that can be attached to the page as follows:

```
let tracks = TwillioVideo.createLocalTracks({
  video: { deviceId: this.state.selectedVideoInput.deviceId },
  audio: { deviceId: this.state.selectedAudioInput.deviceId }
}
//Find dom element to attach tracks to
let previewContainer = document.getElementById('local-media')

//Attach all tracks
this.setState({localTracks: tracks})
tracks.forEach(track => previewContainer.appendChild(track.attach()))
```

`track.attach()` generates a dom element that can be appended but its not something i can put in React state so it can be rendered like so:

```
<div id="local-media">{this.state.localTracks.map(track => track.attach()}</div>
```

If I in fact try to do it i get:

> Unhandled Rejection (Invariant Violation): Objects are not valid as a
>   React child (found: [object HTMLAudioElement]). If you meant to render
>   a collection of children, use an array instead.

**EDIT 1:**
I was able to get rid of error by doing this:

```
{this.state.localTracks.map(track => track.attach().Element)}
```

but it's not returning renderable html but `undefined` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [`attach` method in Twilio Video](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/2.0.0-beta10/docs/VideoTrack.html#attach) can take an argument, which is an `HTMLMediaElement`, and will attach the media to that element.

I would recommend that you create a component you can use to render the media for each media track and then use [React refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to get a pointer to the DOM element.

Something like this:

```
import React, { Component, createRef } from 'react';

class Participant extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.video = createRef();
    this.audio = createRef();
    this.trackAdded = this.trackAdded.bind(this);
  }

  trackAdded(track) {
    if (track.kind === 'video') {
      track.attach(this.video.current);
    } else if (track.kind === 'audio') {
      track.attach(this.audio.current);
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const videoTrack = Array.from(
      this.props.participant.videoTracks.values()
    )[0];
    if (videoTrack) {
      videoTrack.attach(this.video.current);
    }
    const audioTrack = Array.from(
      this.props.participant.audioTracks.values()
    )[0];
    if (audioTrack) {
      audioTrack.attach(this.audio.current);
    }

    this.props.participant.on('trackAdded', this.trackAdded);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="participant">
        <h3>{this.props.participant.identity}</h3>
        <video ref={this.video} autoPlay={true} muted={true} />
        <audio ref={this.audio} autoPlay={true} muted={true} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Participant;
```

Then, for every participant in your chat, you can render one of these component.

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: what should i do if i have arbitrary number of tracks? (multiple users joining dynamically) I need some way of creating mediaElements on the fly

Comment: In this case, for each Participant I render one of these components. You could take it one step further and move the `<video>` and `<audio>` elements to their own components, with individual refs, so you could have multiple for the user. Did you try this approach yet?

Comment: Cool, let me know how it goes!

Comment: philnash, looks like attach() can only take arguments beginning with version 2. but v.2x is still in beta testing, is it safe to use in production environment?

Comment: It is supported in v1 too. Check the docs here: https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.19.2/docs/VideoTrack.html#attach__anchor